# Did using stipe medium planes cause me any loss?

Tags: node.js, stripe-payments, currency, subscription

I made a stripe + nodejs code but I had a doubt, how can I guarantee that the customer actually paid, because my plan is measured by use so pretend that the user used the service 5 times and his bill at the end of the month was 500 dollars, but his balance is 0 but he used the whole month of that service, and even so logically he didn't pay, do I lose money?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you mean that:

1. you have a pay as you go service
2. the user spends a debt during the month
3. your application tries to charge the expense at the end of the month (or at the beginning of the following month)

In this case, if the user's card has no funds, the charge may be denied. Sure, it can happen.

If you lose money? In this scenario, it could happen, but it's not necessarily an insurmountable problem. I mean it depends on the percentage of users that you think might not pay you.

Alternatively, have you evaluated the approach where users "top up" their virtual account in your app?
In this case, you do not risk losing money (and indeed you get it in advance).
But you have to evaluate the friction of users to load their account.

Bottom Line: It really depends on your situation.
Good luck!

Comment: Really... with a little research you can already notice, services like AWS or even simpler ones like heroku work like this, they charge for the use which could possibly be harmful to them but in more complex terms no, after all you wouldn't be using these services to give work yourself, the intention is to facilitate and not create crazy gadgets on top of your own application, it sounds cliché but it would even be true to say that they can trust the ethics of the customers since they also need the good functioning of the services they use.